# Images embedded in Rich Text Field are not getting displayed after doing Mail Merge using Aspose.Words

Tags: richtextbox, rtf, mailmerge, aspose.words

We have one asp.net (C#) web application in which we are providing mail merge functionality. We have used Aspose.Words third party for Mail Merge functionality.

I am using DocumentBuilder.InsertHtml function to insert rich text/html content in document.

When we do mail merge then image embedded in rich text/html content is not always merging in document. If url of image is accessible without authentication then image will merge properly. But, if image url is private and need authentication then this image is not merging in document.

I have googled a lot but do not found any solution. So, is there any solution or work around to merge image with private url embedded in rich text field.

Comment: Please share your input Word and HTML documents along with code that you are using. I will investigate the issue and provide you more information on it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.